# Stored procedure returning outer select same amount of times as inner select

Tags: xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

Running a stored procedure to return all records in a database (phones in this case) and their colour options.

Problem is when a phone has 4 colours for example, it is returning ModelGroup 4 times also.

I know it's probably something obvious, or do i need to put them into a table first?

Stored Procedure:

```
SELECT 

PB.ModelGroup as '@group',

    (SELECT

        PB1.UID as '@pid',
        PB1.Brand as '@brand',
        PB1.Title as '@title',
        PB1.Friendly_URL_Name as '@url',
        PB1.Camera as '@camera',
        PB1.Storage as '@storage',
        PB1.Screen_Size as '@screensize',
        PB1.OS as '@os',
        PB1.Processor as '@chip',
        PB1.Image1 as '@image',
        CB.Colour as '@colour'

    FROM dbo.Phone_Base PB1
    INNER JOIN dbo.Colour_Base CB ON CB.UID = PB1.Colour
    WHERE PB1.Active = 1 AND PB.Title = PB1.Title
    FOR XML PATH('colours'), TYPE
    )

FROM dbo.Phone_Base PB
WHERE PB.Active = 1
ORDER BY PB.ModelGroup

FOR XML PATH('phone'), TYPE
```

XML output:

```
<phone group="iphone6s16gb">
<colours pid="16" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Space-Grey" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-space-grey.png" colour="Space Grey" />
<colours pid="17" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Gold" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-gold.png" colour="Gold" />
<colours pid="18" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Rose-Gold" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-rose-gold.png" colour="Rose Gold" />
<colours pid="19" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Silver" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-silver.png" colour="Silver" />
</phone>
<phone group="iphone6s16gb">
<colours pid="16" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Space-Grey" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-space-grey.png" colour="Space Grey" />
<colours pid="17" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Gold" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-gold.png" colour="Gold" />
<colours pid="18" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Rose-Gold" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-rose-gold.png" colour="Rose Gold" />
<colours pid="19" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Silver" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-silver.png" colour="Silver" />
</phone>
<phone group="iphone6s16gb">
<colours pid="16" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Space-Grey" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-space-grey.png" colour="Space Grey" />
<colours pid="17" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Gold" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-gold.png" colour="Gold" />
<colours pid="18" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Rose-Gold" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-rose-gold.png" colour="Rose Gold" />
<colours pid="19" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Silver" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-silver.png" colour="Silver" />
</phone>
<phone group="iphone6s16gb">
<colours pid="16" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Space-Grey" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-space-grey.png" colour="Space Grey" />
<colours pid="17" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Gold" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-gold.png" colour="Gold" />
<colours pid="18" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Rose-Gold" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-rose-gold.png" colour="Rose Gold" />
<colours pid="19" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Silver" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-silver.png" colour="Silver" />
</phone>
```

Expected XML Result:

```
<phone group="iphone6s16gb">
<colours pid="16" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Space-Grey" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-space-grey.png" colour="Space Grey" />
<colours pid="17" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Gold" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-gold.png" colour="Gold" />
<colours pid="18" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Rose-Gold" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-rose-gold.png" colour="Rose Gold" />
<colours pid="19" brand="1" title="iPhone 6S 16GB" url="iPhone-6S-16GB-Silver" camera="12" storage="16GB" screensize="4.7" os="iOS" chip="A9" image="iphone6s-silver.png" colour="Silver" />
</phone>
```

Table Data:

```
UID Product_Code    SKU           Brand ModelGroup  Title   Short_Title Friendly_URL_Name   Colour  Description Storage Camera  Processor   Screen_Size OS  Extra_Feature   Image1  Image2  Image3  Image4  Trade_Price Network Active  Featured    Created_By  Created Edited_By   Edited  Model
16  IPHONE6S16GBSPACEGREY   NULL    1   iphone6s16gb    iPhone 6S 16GB  iPhone 6S 16GB Space Grey   iPhone-6S-16GB-Space-Grey   3   he moment you use iPhone 6s, you know you’ve never felt anything like it. With just a single press, 3D Touch lets you do more than ever before. Live Photos bring your memories to life in a powerfully vivid way. And that’s just the beginning. Take a deeper look at iPhone 6s, and you’ll find innovation on every level.   16GB    12  A9  4.7 iOS     iphone6s-space-grey.png NULL    NULL    NULL    420.00  1   1   0   1   2016-08-24 14:52:00 NULL    NULL    iPhone6
17  IPHONE6S16GBGOLD    NULL    1   iphone6s16gb    iPhone 6S 16GB  iPhone 6S 16GB Gold iPhone-6S-16GB-Gold 5   he moment you use iPhone 6s, you know you’ve never felt anything like it. With just a single press, 3D Touch lets you do more than ever before. Live Photos bring your memories to life in a powerfully vivid way. And that’s just the beginning. Take a deeper look at iPhone 6s, and you’ll find innovation on every level.   16GB    12  A9  4.7 iOS     iphone6s-gold.png   NULL    NULL    NULL    420.00  1   1   0   1   2016-08-24 14:58:00 NULL    NULL    iPhone6
18  IPHONE6S16GBROSEGOLD    NULL    1   iphone6s16gb    iPhone 6S 16GB  iPhone 6S 16GB Rose Gold    iPhone-6S-16GB-Rose-Gold    6   The moment you use iPhone 6s, you know you’ve never felt anything like it. With just a single press, 3D Touch lets you do more than ever before. Live Photos bring your memories to life in a powerfully vivid way. And that’s just the beginning. Take a deeper look at iPhone 6s, and you’ll find innovation on every level.  16GB    12  A9  4.7 iOS     iphone6s-rose-gold.png  NULL    NULL    NULL    420.00  1   1   0   1   2016-08-24 15:05:00 NULL    NULL    iPhone6
19  IPHONE6S16GBSILVER  NULL    1   iphone6s16gb    iPhone 6S 16GB  iPhone 6S 16GB Silver   iPhone-6S-16GB-Silver   4   The moment you use iPhone 6s, you know you’ve never felt anything like it. With just a single press, 3D Touch lets you do more than ever before. Live Photos bring your memories to life in a powerfully vivid way. And that’s just the beginning. Take a deeper look at iPhone 6s, and you’ll find innovation on every level.  16GB    12  A9  4.7 iOS     iphone6s-silver.png NULL    NULL    NULL    420.00  1   1   0   1   2016-08-24 15:06:00 NULL    NULL    iPhone6
```

Comment: Thx for posting the `Table Data`, but this does not really help: The joined color table is missing and **please**: Reduce your input to the actual problem (e.g. ommit not needed columns). [Best was a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), some real SQL code with table, inserts and your own attempt to make it copy'n'pasteable for us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an actual table this is reading the magic glass bulb, but it could be something like this:

```
SELECT 

PB.ModelGroup as '@group',

    (SELECT

        PB1.UID as '@pid',
        PB1.Brand as '@brand',
        PB1.Title as '@title',
        PB1.Friendly_URL_Name as '@url',
        PB1.Camera as '@camera',
        PB1.Storage as '@storage',
        PB1.Screen_Size as '@screensize',
        PB1.OS as '@os',
        PB1.Processor as '@chip',
        PB1.Image1 as '@image',
        CB.Colour as '@colour'

    FROM dbo.Phone_Base PB1
    INNER JOIN dbo.Colour_Base CB ON CB.UID = PB1.Colour
    WHERE PB1.ModelGroup=PB.ModelGroup
      AND PB1.Active = 1 
      AND PB.Title = PB1.Title
    FOR XML PATH('colours'), TYPE
    )

FROM dbo.Phone_Base PB
WHERE PB.Active = 1
GROUP BY PB.ModelGroup

FOR XML PATH('phone'), TYPE
```

The `GROUP BY` will reduce the outer `SELECT` to one row per ModelGroup. The sub-select adds the ModelGroup to the `WHERE`-clause, thus returning the related rows only...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Couldn't use your exact response due to the where clause so altered grouping back to title.

Comment: Might be enough to add `PB.Active` to your grouping list

Comment: thanks, your answer pointed me in the right direction, see below.

Answer (score 0):

Final and working stored procedure thanks to @Shnugo for the pointer!

```
SELECT 
    PB.Title as '@group',
    (SELECT
        PB1.UID as '@pid',
        PB1.Brand as '@brand',
        PB1.Title as '@title',
        PB1.Friendly_URL_Name as '@url',
        PB1.Camera as '@camera',
        PB1.Storage as '@storage',
        PB1.Screen_Size as '@screensize',
        PB1.OS as '@os',
        PB1.Processor as '@chip',
        PB1.Image1 as '@image',
        CB.Colour as '@colour'
    FROM 
        dbo.Phone_Base PB1
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Colour_Base CB ON CB.UID = PB1.Colour
    WHERE 
        PB1.Active = 1 AND PB.Title = PB1.Title
    FOR XML PATH('colours'), TYPE
    )
FROM 
    dbo.Phone_Base PB
WHERE 
    PB.Active = 1
GROUP BY 
    PB.Title
FOR XML PATH('phone'), TYPE
```